# C# protobuf-net - default value overwrites value from protobuf data

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I need to `serialize/deserialize` classes using protobuf-net. For some properties of my classes, I need to define a default value. I did this by setting the values of the properties. In some cases this default value overwrites the value from the protobuf data.

**Code Sample:**

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var target = new MyClass
        {
            MyBoolean = false
        };

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Serializer.Serialize(stream, target);
            stream.Position = 0;
            var actual = Serializer.Deserialize<MyClass>(stream);
            //actual.MyBoolean will be true
        }
    }
}

[ProtoContract(Name = "MyClass")]
public class MyClass
{
    #region Properties

    [ProtoMember(3, IsRequired = false, Name = "myBoolean", DataFormat = DataFormat.Default)]
    public Boolean MyBoolean { get; set; } = true;

    #endregion
}
```

MyBoolean will have a value of true after deserializing the data.

How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For performance reasons default values are not serialized at all. The default of bool is false. Your default is true. To make this work you have to make your default value known with the `DefaultValueAttribute`:

```
    [ProtoMember( 3, IsRequired = false, Name = "myBoolean", DataFormat =  DataFormat.Default )]
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public Boolean MyBoolean { get; set; } = true;
```

Comment: Ok, but why does my code not work… i mean the property gets set in the constructor of the class… how can this overwrite the value from the protobuf data?

Comment: @musium - The value `false` *isn't* in the protobuf data, because protobuf doesn't think there's any point in serializing it, because false is the default value of a bool. Protobuf doesn't realize that *your* default value for the `MyBoolean` is `true`. More info here: https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=199